# How to convert a strictly sorted list of strings into dict?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tree

I have a strictly sorted list of strings:

```
['a',
 'b',
 'b/c',
 'b/d',
 'e',
 'f',
 'f/g',
 'f/h',
 'f/h/i',
 'f/h/i/j']
```

This list is similar to tree representation. So, I need to convert it to dict:

```
{'a': {},
 'b': {'c': {},
       'd': {}},
 'e': {},
 'f': {'g': {},
       'h': {'i': {'j': {}}}}}
```

As you can see, keys in this dict are parents and values are children.

UPD: I agree that **empty dict** is better than **None**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't insist on `None` as the leaf value, you can use the compact code

```
my_dict = lambda: defaultdict(my_dict)
d = my_dict()
for x in my_list:
    reduce(defaultdict.__getitem__, x.split("/"), d)
```

Admittedly, it isn't *that* obvious what this code does, but it's succinct :)

Answer (score 5):

```
di = {}
for a in arr:
    al = a.split("/")
    d = di
    for elem in al:
        if elem in d:
            d = d[elem]
        else:
            d[elem]={}

print di
```

Note that elemts are not stored in alphabetical order in a dictionary!

Comment: This does not produce the requested result, as it uses `{}` instead of `None` as leaf values.

Comment: @lazyr: Correct, but I think OP is able to adapt it to his needs :) And it would have cluttered the code with checks whether it is None or it is a dict etc, but I think the underlying idea is more important than such implementation details.

Comment: This code fails for `["a", "b/c"]`. It isn't quite clear from the specifications whether this case needs to be covered, though.

Comment: @SvenMarnach this list `["a", "b/c"]` is invalid. It must be `["a", "b", "b/c"]`. Maybe I should have been represented my idea more clearly...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my crack at it. I reverse the path for optimization, because pop() is much faster than pop(0).

```
def add_branch(root, path):
    branch = path.pop()
    if path:
        if branch not in root or root[branch] is None:
            root[branch] = {}
        add_branch(root[branch], path)
    else:
        root[branch] = None

def totree(strings):
    root = {}
    for string in strings:
        path = string.split("/")
        path.reverse()
        add_branch(root, path)
    return root
```

Use like this:

```
my_tree = totree(['a', 'b', 'b/c', 'b/d', 'e', 'f', 'f/g', 'f/h', 
    'f/h/i', 'f/h/i/j'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps, recursive approach :)

```
import pprint

l = ['a',
'b',
'b/c',
'b/d',
'e',
'f',
'f/g',
'f/h',
'f/h/i',
'f/h/i/j']

def put(d, elems):
    f = elems[0]
    if len(elems)==1:
        d[f]=None
    else:
        if f not in d or d[f]==None:
            d[f] = {}
        put(d[f], elems[1:])

d = {}
for x in l:
    put(d, x.split('/'))

pprint.pprint(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my resolution:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

input = ['a', 'b', 'b/c', 'b/d', 'e', 'f', 'f/g', 'f/h', 'f/h/i', 'f/h/i/j']
result = defaultdict(dict)
for i in input:
    path = i.split('/')
    key = path[0]
    value = {}
    buffer = {key:value}
    for folder in path[1:]:
        value[folder] = {}
        value = value[folder]
    result[key].update(buffer[key])
pprint(dict(result))
```