# Tree style dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tree

I am stuck with the following data.

There is a list.

```
[{name: '/', children: [{name: 'bin'}, {name: 'sbin'}, {name: 'home'}]},
{name: 'home', children: [{name: 'user1'}, {name: 'user2'}]},
{name: 'user2', children: [{name: 'desktop'}]}]
```

I want to convert above list to the following dictionary.

```
{name: '/', children: [{name: '/bin'}, {name: '/sbin'}, {name: '/home', children: [{name: 'user1'}, {name: 'user2', children: [{name: 'desktop'}]}]}]}
```

I write some codes to convert data above style.

```
def recT(data, child, parent, collector):
    dparent = dict(name=parent)
    dchildren = dict()
    lst = []
    for c in child:
        lst.append(dict(name=c['name']))
        for d in data:
            if c['name'] == d['name']:
                if len(d) > 1:
                    dchildren.update(dict(children=recT(data, d['children'], d['name'], collector)))
    dparent.update(dchildren)
    collector.update(dparent)
    return lst
```

Then,

```
myd = dict()
for d in data2:
    if len(d) > 1:
        recT(data2, d['children'], d['name'], myd)
```

NOTE: data2 is dictionary list I want to covert.

But, the output dictionary is the last record in list:

```
{'children': [{'name': 'desktop'}], 'name': 'user2'}
```

Please help.

Comment: Show us your code so we can help ...

Comment: I hope you realize that the list data structure does not handle two directories with the same name anywhere in the tree (e.g. /bin and /usr/bin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lazyr said, you can't duplicate keys in your `dict` like that. You could convert it to a format like the following to be valid python `dict` syntax:

```
{
  '/': {
    'bin': {}, 
    'sbin': {}, 
    'home': {
      'user1': {},
      'user2': {
        'desktop': {}
      }
  }
}
```

The reason you're only getting the last record in the list is because your dict uses **unique keys**

```
mydict = {}
mydict['name'] = 1
mydict['name'] # is 1
mydict['name'] = 2

for x,y in mydict.iteritems():
  print '{0}: {1}'.format(x,y)
>> name: 2 # Note only one entry
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I got it from @lazyr's answer of [How to convert a strictly sorted list of strings into dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818245/how-to-convert-a-strictly-sorted-list-of-strings-into-dict).

Then, I converted into string and changed it into wanted format using myReplacer().

here:

```
def myReplacer(strdata):
    strdata = strdata.replace("{", '{ name:')
    strdata = strdata.replace(': {', ', children : [{')
    strdata = strdata.replace('}', '}]')
    strdata = strdata.replace(': None,', '},{ name:')
    strdata = strdata.replace(': None', '')
    strdata = strdata.replace(", '", "}, { name: '")
    return strdata[:-1]
```

Thanks @lazyr and everybody helped me. It need some polish.